# How to filter Magento collection for a date or null

Tags: magento

I have some Magento code that I'm trying to use to filter a collection of products. I want to find all products where the date is BEFORE a certain date OR the date hasn't been set (ie is null).

I have:

```html
function getProduct($product_id) {
 global $proxy, $sessionId, $conn, $start_date, $time_to_run;
 if ($product_id == 'all') {
  $result=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('price_adjust_active', array('null' => true))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('price_adjust_active', '1')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=> 'price_adjust_last_run','lt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_to_run)),
        array('attribute'=> 'price_adjust_last_run', 'null' => true)
    ))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))      
    ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
    ->setPageSize(1);
    } else {
     
  $result=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $product_id))
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('price_adjust_active', array('null' => true))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('price_adjust_active', '1')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=> 'price_adjust_last_run','lt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_to_run)),
        array('attribute'=> 'price_adjust_last_run', 'null' => true)
    ))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))      
    ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
    ->setPageSize(1);
 }
```

and I can successfully filter out the products with the dates set before my specified date. I just can't get the "null" attribute to work. As you can see from my code, I have 2 different filters in there, and neither of them seem to give me the desired results.

The two faulty attempts are:

->addAttributeToFilter('price_adjust_active', array('null' => true))

or

array('attribute'=> 'price_adjust_last_run', 'null' => true)

Comment: use can use like this 

->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')

Comment: you can find the code in this file 
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\New.php

Answer (score 2):

Magento has a special way to filter dates instead of just using a straight greater or less than.

Try this...

```
->addAttributeToFilter('price_adjust_last_run', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array(
        'date' => true,
        'from' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_to_run - 1)
    ),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
```

You are setting `date` to `true` and then you'll probably want to make sure to subtract 1 second from your `$time_to_run` variable.

This works similarly with `addFieldToFilter()` as well.